# C++/CLI shorthand properties

Tags: properties, c++-cli, shorthand

How does a developer do the equivalent of this in managed c++? :

c# code

```
public String SomeValue
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

I've scoured the net and found some solutions, however it is hard to distinguish which is the correct (latest, .NET 3.5) way, given the colourful history of getters/setters and managed c++.

Thanks!

Comment: Managed C++ is out of date. C++/CLI is the current method.

Comment: Sorry, C++/CLI is what I am using.  I still use the old name :(

Comment: DanDan: C++/CLI is an entirely different language. While it's a successor to Managed C++, Managed C++ is not really its old name.

Comment: I'll make sure I use the correct name for the correct language.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Managed C++ does not support automatic properties. You should manually declare a backing field and the accessors:

```
private: String* _internalSomeValue;
public:
__property String* get_SomeValue() { return _internalSomeValue; }
__property void set_SomeValue(String *value) { _internalSomeValue = value; }
```

C++/CLI supports automatic properties with a very simple syntax:

```
public: property String^ SomeValue;
```

#### Update (reply to comment):

In C++/CLI, you cannot control the accessibility of each accessor method separately when you use the automatic property syntax. You need to define the backing field and the methods yourself:

```
private: String^ field;
property String^ SomeValue { 
   public: String^ get() { return field; }
   private: void set(String^ value) { field = value; }
}
```

Comment: In the C++/CLI version, how would I make the setter private, for example?

Answer (score 20):

In C++/CLI you would do just:

```
property String^ SomeValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to give you more search terms, this is called a *trivial property*