# Different access modifiers for property getter/setter in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Is it possible to specify different access modifiers for property getter and setter using C++/CLI syntax? In C# one would write:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public string Bar
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do:

```
public:
    property String^ Bar
    {
        String^ get();
    private:
        void set(String^);
    }
```

(Edited following Hans Passant's comment).

Comment: That doesn't compile cleanly.  Use *public:* in front of property and just plain *private:* before the setter.

Comment: @HansPassant This will compile but not link. This link https://stackoverflow.com/a/1907836/1008943 claims automatic properties with different access levels are not possible unless you define the function definition.